# "Screen position out of view frustum" errors followed by "Assertion failed on expression: 'std::abs(det) > FLT_MIN'" - Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, frustum

So in my game you are a sphere rolling down ramps, but if you go too fast and crash into a ledge the game freezes and the console gets spammed with the first error in the title followed by the second one. I managed to find what line of code caused this problem, here's that script:

```
public class FöljaBoll : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject player;
   public float yOffset;
   public float zOffset;

   Transform playerPosition;
   Transform cameraPosition;

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    playerPosition = player.GetComponent<Transform>();
    cameraPosition = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    if (playerPosition == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    cameraPosition.position = playerPosition.position + new Vector3(0, +yOffset, -zOffset);
  }

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (player == null)
    {
       return;
    }
    else
    {
        float speed = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z + 6;
        float targetFOV = (float)Math.Log(speed, 1.1) + 34;
        GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, targetFOV, (float)0.1);
    }
  }
}
```

So what it does is it sets the FOV based on the player speed through a logarithmic function in order for it to not get out of control at high speeds, but for some reason this part (I commented it out and wasn't able to recreate the errors):

`GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, targetFOV, (float)0.1);`

triggers the error messages. If anyone could help me out here that would be awesome, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself by setting the bounciness of the Physics Material attached to both the ramps and the sphere to 0. This post: https://answers.unity.com/questions/9985/limiting-rigidbody-velocity.html said that bounciness combined with high velocities can cause problems and that seems to have been the problem.